# How to write key input in assembly?

Tags: linux, windows, assembly

I'm trying to make a keyboard driver for windows & linux as a project, I was looking to simulate the actual process of writing a key (meaning not using anything such as windows messages), and after move on to the waiting for input from keyboard which I found alot of tutorials for.
Anyone know hot to do this for Windows & Linux? (running intel proc win10 64bit & kali linux amd proc 64bit)

Comment: Why do you need to write a keyboard driver? What additional features do you need it to have? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52941047/edit) your question to improve it a lot, by adding more context and motivation and explaining your goals

Comment: Are you asking how to make an assembly program that _reads_ keyboard input as it is received by the computer or _gets_ keyboard input from the computer? The first is simple, and I can answer that. The latter is _extremely_ difficult. I daresay it is relatively impossible even. Just imagine all the documentation you would have to read to find out, documentation that probably isn't even available in the case of windows. It's not really something that a programmer ever needs to do, unless he is working on operating system development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have the same driver on Windows and on Linux. You'll need to make two different, unrelated, programs and you have to design them differently (because Windows and Linux have different architectures for drivers).

BTW, on Linux, with a graphical desktop, a [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server) (such as [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server) or [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol))) is running. That server is the only program handling the physical keyboard. You might consider working with it.

The actual notion of keyboard driver is too broad to make a concrete sense. On Linux, you could patch the kernel, patch the display server, improve the [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager), etc... There is no need, and not much interest, in coding that stuff in assembler.

Notice that on Linux, with a graphical desktop, the keyboard layout is handled in the display server, not in kernel code (so the kernel is sending key events with keycodes close to [scancodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode), not characters; the Xorg server sends keyboard events with similar keycodes to e.g. the window manager). Read more about the [X Window System protocols and architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_protocols_and_architecture) and e.g. [EWMH](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html). The graphical layers are very complex (both on Linux and on Windows), many millions of lines of code.

Comment: I want to code this in assembly because I can't code it in C++, not that I know of a way at least without getting extremely complicated, I know it's not interesting but I do want to do it, I know I have to make 2 different programs so I guess I was looking for 2 answers here, one for windows and one for linux. Just the writing process, the keyboard is the easier part.

Comment: Do you realize that it could take you at least *years* of work, and probably more than your lifetime?

Comment: years of work to just create a driver for my specific windows and linux OS? that doesn't sound right, isn't there any way I can just write the key as if it was input from a real driver without doing it extremely complicated?

Comment: Read more the links I have given you.... You cannot imagine the complexity of what you want to code. You need to understand millions of lines of source code (but on Linux, all that is free software, so in theory you can study it)

Comment: hmm, I'll read it yeah and I understand, I thought there is an easy way like a function or something that I could use to write the key to windows / linux. I was thinking of making it a virtual one not a physical one and then wait for the input of a keyboard that's already with a driver if you get that. Anyways thanks for the help!

Comment: There is no *easy* way. And we don't understand your actual goal. Is it a keyboard spoofer, or for changing the keyboard layout (e.g. to be able to conveniently input weird UTF8 characters), etc.... BTW Linux is fully opensource, so why don't you start studying the source code (of Xorg, of the kernel, of the window manager, etc...) and ask focused questions about it

Comment: For example, studying the source code of Xorg and understanding how keyboard events are handled in it will take you several months of your time. the X11 protocol is more complex than what you think.

Comment: I just want to make an input "spoofer" I guess you could call it that would look real as in as if I pressed an actual key. It doesn't have to be complicated I just want it to look real and that would do the trick if it's too complicated

Comment: Such a keyboard spoofer *will be complicated* and you could need more than a year of work to make it